# Why aren't two objects the same, after assigning one to the other?

Tags: c++

We had some weird misbehavior in our vector class. It taught us a valuable lesson.

```
class Vector3D
{
    float x, y, z, w;
public:
    Vector3D( float ax, float ay, float az, float aw )
        : x(ax), y(ay), z(az), w(aw)
    {}
    Vector3D( float ax, float ay, float az ) // for when you don't care about w
        : x(ax), y(ay), z(az)
    {}

    void Assign( const Vector3D& rhs )
    {
        x = rhs.x;
        y = rhs.y;
        z = rhs.z;
        w = rhs.w;
    }
    bool operator==( const Vector3D& o )
    {
        return (x==o.x && y==o.y && z==o.z && w==o.w);
    }
    // lots more stuff
}

int main()
{
    Vector3D a(1.0f,2.0f,3.0f);
    Vector3D b(4.0f,5.0f,6.0f);

    a.Assign(b);
    bool result=(a==b); // Expected: true. Actual: false, sometimes
}
```

For a while it looked like there was a bug in the `Assign` function. We would use it to copy the value of one vector to another, but later on the code would fail to match points that we knew should be identical. Data breakpoints were set, and failed to be hit. Heads were scratched. Eventually we added code to the end of `Assign` that immediately called `operator==` to check that the two vectors were the same... and they weren't.

What went wrong?

Comment: A [mcve] would really help here.

Comment: Agreed on the MCVE, but disagreed on the "is floating-point math broken" - the use-case here is equality after assignment, which ought to be uncontroversial :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes indeed, good catch!

Comment: Also `NaN` is not `==` to `NaN`. Floats are awesome.

Comment: Are you maybe assigning to a `vector` where `w` is uninitialised?

Comment: float x, y, z, w; default value?

Comment: @Mat - Oh, yes that's a good one.  In particular, the case that `w` is uninitialised in some cases could lead to this inadvertently.

Comment: Related to George's comment: does the 3-argument constructor initialize `w` to something (even if it is just zero)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've included the definitions of the constructors.

Comment: @juanchopanza This is difficult to reproduce because of it's nature, but I've included some test code that should at least illustrate the expected and observed behavior

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that the second constructor, the one taking just 3 parameters, wasn't initializing `w`. We were very concerned about the performance of our code, and in cases where we knew we would only use `x`.`y`,and `z` we didn't want to use any CPU power on the fourth member variable.

Eventually, we ended up seeing an object whose `w` happened to contain a pattern of bits corresponding to IEEE NaN. One of the interesting things about those is that when you compare NaN to NaN, the comparison always fails, even if the bit patterns are the same. So our `operator==` method, comparing uninitialized `w` values, decided that the two were not the same.

Lesson learned: **never use uninitialized data**.

Comment: The constructor definitions need to be included in the question.  BTW, it's not just "the memory happened to contain a NaN encoding"... doing anything with uninitialized values formally causes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: You could just assume the `w` component redundant, and have a special point class.

Comment: @George that's a reasonable suggestion. The thinking at the time was that, data alignment considerations being what they were, we wouldn't save any memory with the smaller class, and there would be a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Lesson learned.  Quite - it's just asking for trouble.